# Dimension of a sheaf cohomology group on a genus 1 curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, exact-sequence, moduli-space

Let $\mathcal{M}_{g,1}$ be the moduli space of genus 1 curves with 1 puncture. For simplicity let's take $g > 1$. As usual, there is a natural fibration $C \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{g,1} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{g}$. As such, one has the natural short exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow T_{C} \rightarrow T\mathcal{M}_{g,1}|_C \rightarrow N_C \rightarrow 0$$

where $T_C$ and $N_C$ are tangent and normal bundles of $C$. As usual, there is an associated long exact sequence of cohomology:

$$0 \rightarrow H^0(C, T_{C}) \rightarrow H^0(C,T\mathcal{M}_{g,1}|_C) \rightarrow H^0(C, N_C) \rightarrow H^1(C, T_{C}) \rightarrow H^1(C,T\mathcal{M}_{g,1}|_C) \rightarrow H^1(C, N_C) \rightarrow 0.$$

Some easy facts:

- $H^0(C, T_{C}) = 0$ for $g > 1$.
- $H^1(C, TC) \simeq \mathbb{C}^{3g - 3}$.
- $N_C \simeq H^1(C, TC) \otimes \mathcal{O}_C$.
- $H^0(C, N_C) \simeq H^1(C, TC) \otimes \mathbb{C}$.
- $H^1(C, N_C) \simeq H^1(C, TC) \otimes \mathbb{C}^{g}$.

Two questions:

1) Is the normal bundle sequence split?

2) What is the dimension of $H^0(C, T\mathcal{M}_{g,1}|_C)$?

Comment: Hint: if $C$ corresponds to a smooth point of $M_g$, then $N_C$ is a trivial bundle (whose rank is the dimension of the moduli space). Combining this with your knowledge of $T_C$ will give the answer in this case.

Comment: I actually tried that first. In that case, $N_C$ is simply $H^1(C, T_C) \otimes \mathcal{O}$. But from the long exact sequence of cohomology all I can get is that the difference between the dimensions of $H^1(C, T\mathcal{M}_{g,1}|_C)$ and $H^0(C, T\mathcal{M}_{g,1}|_C)$ is $g(3g - 3)$, which can also be obtained directly from Riemann-Roch. But I couldn't go any further.

Comment: I think the missing ingredient here is that the tangent space of the point $[C] \in M_g$, which by pullback is the same as $H^0(C,N_C)$, maps _isomorphically_ to $H^1(C,TC)$ by the Kodaira--Spencer map.

Comment: The isomorphism $T\mathcal{M}_g|_C \simeq H^1(C, TC)$ is an immediate consequence of the usual deformation theory. It was used to express various terms in the long exact sequence of cohomology. But I don't see how it helps further in this case.

Comment: In fact, one can say more: the tangent space $T\mathcal{M}_{g,1}|_{C}$ is isomorphic to $H^1(C, TC \otimes \mathcal{O(-p)})$, namely $H^1$ with values in vector fields that vanish at the puncture $p\in C$. But I haven't been able to find these statements useful.

Comment: If you know that map is an isomorphism, then the previous map in the l.e.s. must be zero.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I see it now. Thank you all.